# Retrieve 'tr' by text of children

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I want to select a `tr` by the text it contains, including the text of the children.
My html is as follows:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl21_Label4">Sanskrit</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl21_Label2">0655-0700 </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl21_LinkButtonDownloadPdf" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl21$LinkButtonDownloadPdf','')" style="color: Navy;
            font-weight: bold;">Download</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl21_Label3">24 October</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl22_Label4">Sanskrit</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl22_Label2">1810-1815 </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl22_LinkButtonDownloadPdf" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl22$LinkButtonDownloadPdf','')" style="color: Navy;
            font-weight: bold;">Download</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl22_Label3">23 October</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I load it thus `_soup = soup(html, "html.parser")`.

If i run `_soup.find("span", text="Sanskrit").parent.parent.text` then I get the result `'\n\nSanskrit\n\n\n0655-0700 \n\n\nDownload\n\n\n24 October\n\n'`

but if i run `print(_soup.find("tr", text='\n\nSanskrit\n\n\n0655-0700 \n\n\nDownload\n\n\n24 October\n\n'))`

i get `None`

Comment: Could you clarify, why you wanna search for `\n\nSanskrit\n\n\n0655-0700 \n\n\nDownload\n\n\n24 October\n\n` and not by a part of it, like *Sanskrit* or *0655-0700* or *Download*?

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is that `text` needs an exact match - You could `regex` or use `css selectors` and `:-soup-contains()`:

```
soup.select('tr:has(:-soup-contains("Sanskrit"))')
```

or based on comment, check if your text is in `<tr>`s text:

```
for row in soup.select('tr'):
    if '\n\nSanskrit\n\n\n0655-0700 \n\n\nDownload\n\n\n24 October\n\n' in row.text:
        print(row)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl21_Label4">Sanskrit</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl21_Label2">0655-0700 </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl21_LinkButtonDownloadPdf" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl21$LinkButtonDownloadPdf','')" style="color: Navy;
            font-weight: bold;">Download</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl21_Label3">24 October</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl22_Label4">Sanskrit</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl22_Label2">1810-1815 </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl22_LinkButtonDownloadPdf" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl22$LinkButtonDownloadPdf','')" style="color: Navy;
            font-weight: bold;">Download</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl22_Label3">23 October</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select('tr:has(:-soup-contains("Sanskrit"))')
```

Comment: You mean something like this `print(_soup.select('tr:has(:-soup-contains("Sanskrit\\n\\n\\n0655-0700 \\n\\n\\nDownload\\n\\n\\n24 October"))'))`

Comment: If you have the text of your `tr` you can check it directly with if statement, but I am not sure if this make sense.